# Sum Rows of Data

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, rows

I'm trying to get Rows of data to Sum when a check number is the same.

```
select
 chkdetail_t.check_acct,
 chkheader_t.acct_number,
 chkdetail_t.check_number,
  SUM(CASE WHEN chkdetail_t.check_number = chkdetail_t.check_number THEN  chkdetail_t.amount ELSE NULL END)  AS chek_total,
 convert(VARCHAR(10),CAST(chkdetail_t.check_date as datetime), 101) AS chk_date,
 chkdetail_t.amount,
 chkdetail_t.vend_name,
 chkdetail_t.chk_status,
 chkdetail_t.reconsiled,
 chkdetail_t.chk_type


 from dbo.chkdetail_t
 join dbo.chkheader_t
 on chkheader_t.check_acct = chkdetail_t.check_acct


 where chkdetail_t.check_acct = 'HUNTINGTON'
 and chkdetail_t.chk_status not in ('V', 'R')
 and chkdetail_t.chk_type != 'R'
 and chkdetail_t.reconsiled = 0

 group by chkdetail_t.check_acct,
chkheader_t.acct_number, 
chkdetail_t.check_number, 
chkdetail_t.check_date,
chkdetail_t.amount,
chkdetail_t.vend_name,
chkdetail_t.chk_status,
chkdetail_t.reconsiled,
chkdetail_t.chk_type

check_number    chek_total
065757          50.00
065757          522.20
065757          581.70
065757          4492.88
065757          4832.92
```

I need to scan the check_number rows from top to bottom and find the ones that equal each other so I can calculate the sum of each check number.

Comment: I can't quite see the forest for the trees, but I suspect you want `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not clear to me exactly what the nature of your question is. Is your query giving you an error message? If so, what is the error? Otherwise, how are the results of the query different from what you expect? Please update your question with some more details regarding the nature of your problem, and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: I'm sorry everyone. I was going to post an image that explains everything but I don't have enough points yet to display the image.  What I am trying to do is take a check number which repeats in multiple rows and then Sum the corresponding amount for a total.  We can get multiple vendor invoices and we will pay with one check.  This is why the check number is repeating  itself.  So I'm trying to create ONE total per check number.  To do this I need to set up a condition If Check_number = Check_number then Sum the corresponding amounts to create a total.  Does this make sense?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome Brian.  Hope I bring something to the table in the future.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT T.Check_Number, SUM(T.amount)
FROM chkdetail_t AS D
JOIN cheheader_t AS H
  ON H.check_acct = T.check_acct
GROUP BY T.check_Number
```

Comment: i was using the wrong column, who knows if this is what he wants.  confusing question.

Comment: Sorry once again.  I gave further detail above.

Comment: ok, i will try again...  i updated my answer...  not sure if i understand.  but this query will join the header to the detail and sum the detail

Comment: The header is joined just because I have to pull one column, account number, from that table.  The meat is in the details table.

Comment: then my query will work... i don't know why you can't explain this better...  about to give up on this one.

Comment: The query by itself works as a charm.  I guess I over thought this.  I'm going to add it to my full query now.  Thank you so MUCH!  Let me take this for a spin.  :-)

Comment: You rock!  I was making this way harder then it was.  Thank you SO MUCH!

Comment: I can't upvote.  I need 15 points still.  Don't know why you got a downvote.  The solution worked.